# Team Foundation Server code review error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm using tfs and when I try to request a code review I get the error in the image bellow. I am able to perform check-ins and shelves.
The other users from the team that I am in are able to request a code review from the same user and in the same path that I am using.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your team users except you works well. I was wondering if it is related to your VS.

For this issue, you can try below methods to see if you can fix it:

1. Repair your VS
2. Try to delete TFS cache by going into default `C:\ {User Profile
   Folder}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache` and VS
   cache in `Appdata` folder.
3. Try to use your account on another computer or use another account
   on your computer to request a code review.(Make sure your account of
   permissions without any problem)

Comment: I tried login in with a user with which requesting a review worked and on that machine it didn't, so i guess Visual Studio is the issue I will try to reinstall it, but now that i know that the machine is the problem i consider the issue resolved, thank you